# traceroute dropping in between for some systems

Tags: ping, traceroute

In my office there are multiple computers running on windows 7. there is one endpoint which can be accessed only from some systems(all system are in the same network).

The endpoint is something like citrixabcd2.test.com. The ping is working only in somemachines. The other machines it is failing. When i do a tracert, all systems are able to recognize the ip address of the endpoint, but tracert is dropping in between for the failing systems.

Do i have to make any entries in the registry editor for the failing systems?.... I am not getting a hint here, on how to start...

Comment: Dropping in-between what and what?

Comment: You get something like "* * * Request timed out"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output from 1 successful and 1 failed tracert.

Comment: Yes I get *Request timed out", from a particular hop